# Custom layout inside FragmentGridPagerAdapter

Tags: android-fragments, wear-os, android-cards

I am trying to add a custom layout page within cards.

Here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/2d-picker.html

explains that CardFragment can easily add a card by:

```
CardFragment fragment = CardFragment.create(title, text, page.iconRes);
```

now if I decided I want to have a custom layout, how do I add it instead of creating a CardFragment?

Check this image:

[image]

The third page is a full screen custom layout. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FragmentGridPagerAdapter` can actually support any subclass of `Fragment` that you need to use. `CardFragment` is just a convenience for a standard wearable layout.

So, you can just create a custom Fragment with a simple layout (such as a full-size `ImageView`) and return it for the appropriate page index.

Answer (score 2):

On getFragment(int row, int col) method from your FragmentGridPagerAdapter class, you can create as many fragments as you want.

you just need to test your row/col values in order to instantiate your fragment class in the correct position.

In your case, something like this:

```
public Fragment getFragment(int row, int col) {

    Fragment fragment;
    if (row == 0 && col == 2) {
        fragment = new YourFullScreenFragment();
    } else {
        fragment = CardFragment.create(title, text, page.iconRes);
    }

    return fragment;

}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`CardFrame` is probably that one that you are looking for - it very similar to `CardFragment` but you can implement your own layout to it. Also as matiash pointed you can use any fragment that you like in such structure.